# Programmatically matching a package name to a full package name

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to get a good way of automatically running appcert.exe in an easy way.

I can not for the life of me figure out how to get the full package name of a package. For instance, I have an application titled `TwitterDemo`, yet when I run Get-AppxPackage, that application doesn't even appear to be listed(probably listed as something like `c2934-289aa9-394...`. Also, I really had rather not rely on using Get-AppxPackage from powershell and then parsing it's output and/or moving it to regular command line. There doesn't even appear to be an API for querying the package database from .Net, and the C++ API seems rather complex.

So basically, what's the easiest way of matching an applications "title" to it's full package name?

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this?  There might be a better way of doing what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @mydogisbox well, what I really need to do is take an appx package, install it, certify it, and then uninstall it. After installing the appx though, there doesn't appear to be a way to get the full package name... there also doesn't seem to be an official api(other than powershell) with which to install and uninstall an app with

Comment: Ah, ok.  That's helpful.  I don't know the answer, but now I _know_ I don't know the answer. ;-)

Comment: @Earlz you can determine the Package Full Name for a package w/o having it installed. See my answer for re: PackageFullNameFromId(). Also, there _is_ a programmatic API -- PackageManager has methods to do pretty much everything the Powershell cmdlets do (and maybe a bit more). see my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to determine the Package Full Name for a package. Do you have a running process, an installed package or merely definitional information?

If you have a running process, [GetPackageFullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446605.aspx)() is the best way.

If you have an installed package, Powershell is probably the most convenient for human. To list all packages installed for the current user:
    powershell -c $(Get-AppxPackage).PackageFullName
You can do the equivalent programmatically via [PackageManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240960.aspx)'s [FindPackages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240969.aspx)() method.

If you just know a package's identity you can calculate its Package Full Name via [PackageFullNameFromId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446771.aspx)()

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are writing an outside app to automate appcert.  I am also assuming that this is a win32 app.  If this is the case, you can use the win32 API [GetPackageFullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the full name a pacakge, given a process handle.  So in the example below, I added a listbox and button to an app and then have the following code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetPackageFullName(IntPtr hProcess, ref UInt32 packageFullNameLength, StringBuilder fullName);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.DataSource = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();

    listBox1.DisplayMember = "ProcessName";
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var proc = listBox1.SelectedItem as System.Diagnostics.Process;
    uint len = 250;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    var err =  GetPackageFullName(proc.Handle, ref len, sb);

    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way is to use the Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager. This doesn't completely solve the problem, but I think my design was a bit too broad in scope.